# Impossible to edit nodes, log to in etcetera after enabling Boost and editing .htaccess

Tags: 7, .htaccess, caching

After installing and enabling [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) in my Drupal 7 site (locally on WAMP and I also tried it on a remote test site) it's not possible to send any forms, e.g. not possible to edit and save nodes, not possible to login etcetera.

The actual Boost caching works though. When I remove the generated htaccess rules from my .htaccess file, everything works as normal again (except that the Boost caching stops to work of course).

My guess is that it's something in the generated htaccess rules that my site does not approve of.

Here is how the added rows look like:

```
  ### BOOST START ###

  # Allow for alt paths to be set via htaccess rules; allows for cached variants (future mobile support)
  RewriteRule .* - [E=boostpath:normal]

#  # Apache 2.4 bug workaround
#  # Enables Search from home page https://drupal.org/node/2078595#comment-8724321
#  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST)$
#  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
#  RewriteRule .* / [S=3]

  # Caching for anonymous users
  # Skip boost IF not get request OR uri has wrong dir OR cookie is set OR request came from this server OR https request
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD)$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(admin|cache|misc|modules|sites|system|openid|themes|node/add|comment/reply))|(/(edit|user|user/(login|password|register))$) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID [OR]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
  RewriteRule .* - [S=2]

#  # Apache 2.4 bug workaround
#  # Enables caching of index/ home page
#  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
#  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}/\_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
#  RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}/\_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]

  # NORMAL
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]

  ### BOOST END ###
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Since you are running WAMP, you are probably running Apache 2.4 and as such you should probably uncomment the Apache 2.4 lines (though that is probably not the cause of the problem, you might forget about it later if you don't do it now). Since form submission is a `POST` request to `user/login` boost should fail on the request method and the request uri rules. Are you sure you followed the [installation instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1459690) properly?

Comment: It turns out that this was an issue solved by this [thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1416214). Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that my question had an answer in this [thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1416214).

So I went back to Boost version 1.0, generated the htaccess code, pasted it in my .htaccess file and then updated to version 1.1 again (without changing the .htaccess file). Now everything seem to work fine.